# code blocks memory limit

Tags: c++, memory-management, codeblocks, memory-limit

How can I increase the memory limit for a C Program. I am using code blocks and trying the following code -

```
int arr[10000000]
```

It is giving me run-time error. I am using Linux(Fedora).
Any help...?

Comment: `ulimit -s unlimited` if you're really hard-core. But you could also allocate such a big one on the heap.

Comment: can u tell me where to put this `ulimit` statement....?

Comment: Never worked with Code::Blocks, so I don't know (would be the shell if you run the programme normally). But I wouldn't recommend it anyway. That remark was tongue-in-cheek. `int *arr = new int[10000000];` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Where does this declaration occur?  I think it should fit in the
memory of a Linux machine, but probably not on the stack, unless
you take special actions (e.g. `ulimit -s`).  In general, it's
not a good idea to use large local C style arrays—in fact,
except in special cases, it's not a good idea to use local
arrays at all.  Just define it as you would any normal array in
C++:

```
std::vector<int> arr( 10000000 );
```

This will move the actual data on to the heap, which is probably
where such large data sets belong.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[10000000];
```

It works for me.. I don't think this depends on C::B, I think this is from your computer.

Comment: Any idea on how i can increase the memory limit or correct this problem..?